# Why is my code throwing a HTTP 500 Error?

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I've been looking at it for like an hour and I dunno why it's throwing a 500 error. It's gonna be something really obvious but I'm not seeing it. Would greatly appreciated help. $connected is basically just how it connects to the database (it does work)

```
/*Starts creating the table to host the tasks */
echo "<table align='center' border='2px' style='width:1000px; line-height: 30px;'>";
echo "<tr>";
/* Names of table headers */
echo "<th> Task Name </th>";
echo "<th> Priority </th>";
echo "<th> Date Due </th>";
echo "<th> Comments </th>";
echo "</tr>";
$tasksquery = "SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE projectcode = '{$_GET['project']}'";
$tasksfinal = mysqli_query($connected, $tasksquery);

if ($tasksfinal) {
        if (mysqli_num_rows($tasksfinal)) > 0 {
                while($tablerows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tasksfinal)) {
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>" . $tablerows['name'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $tablerows['priority'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $tablerows['date'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $tablerows['comments'] . "</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                    }
                }
            }

else {
        echo "Error";
    }
```

Comment: `(mysqli_num_rows($tasksfinal)) > 0`

Comment: @kuh-chan Thanks dude. Sorry for the stupid question. My brain's gone today.

Comment: Your server logs should tell you why.

Comment: And SQL injection. Not cool.